# Using large amount of data stored in a dictionary to create a new dictionary where each key value pair requires unique manipulation

Tags: c#, dictionary, naming-conventions

I have a large dictionary (inpData) which contains data input from a user form. I need to create a new dictionary (outData) in which the keys / values will be dependent on the inpData, logic statements and lookup tables will be required. In the future I want to include some form of validation on the inpData.

My current approach is as follows:

1. Create a class for each sub-table of the outData dictionary.
2. Use the constructor to perform the manipulation from the inpData table to a Property of the class.
3. I will then create a function to combine the Properties into a dictionary for amalgamation.

Example below:

```
    internal class LocationData
    {
        //Properties

        private string locationType { get; set; }
        private string locationValue { get; set; }

        //Constructor

        public LocationData(Dictionary<string, object> inpData)
        {
            this.locationType = (string)inpData["locationType"];

            switch (this.locationType)
            {
                case "MECD":
                    locationValue = "High";
                    break;
                case "LECD":
                    locationValue = "Low";
                    break;
            }




        }
```

My question is whether this follows a best practise approach / whether there is a better way to do such a task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks good but I have a few comments.

you could have a dictionary for the mapping of (MECD and High....) so you don't require `switch` `case` here and you can use this dictionary at other places also in your project.

you can also handle the case when the item is not found in the dictionary.

I think `locationValue`  variable name should be changed to something `locationRating` for good readability.

Comment: Thank you - yes agree with the dictionary point. Where would be the most appropriate place to create the dictionary? Potentially as a static field of the class? Wanting to avoid overcrowding the constructor with large dictionaries.

Comment: @Rock1432 it depends on your requirement. and if this dictionary has 5-10 records. its a very less size. you can even store this mapping in a config file as well.